# URL Rewrite Module - Redirect http to https to particular port

Tags: ssl, iis, https, iis-8

I am using URL Rewrite to redirect HTTP to HTTPS.
All the steps are done & working including the changes in web.config.
https://www.sslshopper.com/iis7-redirect-http-to-https.html

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="RedirectToHTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{SERVER_NAME}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>       
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

I am facing the below issue while redirecting.

I want to redirect the application to a port 90.
I have 2 applications, one is on default port & another is on 90 port.

So when somebody access -
http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:90 then it is redirecting to  :-
https://xxx.xxx.x.xxx

i want it to redirect to https://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:90

Any thought on how to do this?

Comment: Port 90 won't be able to handle both HTTP and HTTPS, so do you really want to do that?

Comment: @LexLi Is there any solution?

Comment: You wanted solution for what?

Comment: Is your issue solved? If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue. If your issue still exists then try to refer the solution given by the community members. If then also you have any further questions then let us know about it. We will try to provide further suggestions to solve the issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

It is not safe to use any other port with https. the default port for the https is 443.so it is recommended to use the default https port.

if you still want to use the different port with your HTTP binding then make sure your site binding is correct.

[image]

use the below rule to redirect the HTTP to https;

```
 <rule name="redirect https" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://192.168.3.66:90/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
```

set the redirect URL based on requirement with https and port 90.

[image]